# (V)C++ (2010) regular expressions, "recursive captures"

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++

I want match and capture operators and operands of an expression like:

- 1
- x
- 1 + x
- x + y + 3 + 10
- etc...

So on regexpal,

```
(\w+)(\s*([+])\s*(\w+))*
```

Appears to do it, but how do I obtain the matched captures? Notice [+] and (\w+) is already in 1 capture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible (at least in any regex flavor that I know of). If one capturing group is used multiple times, the capture will always be filled with the last thing it captured. Simpley example: `([a-z])*` applied to `abc` will give you only `c`.

I recommend that you use the regex just to check for a valid format. Then you can split the string at the matches of `\s*\b\s*`. This should then result in an array containing `x`, `+`, `y`, `+`, `3`, `+`, `10` for your last example.

[Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_token_iterator.html#boost%5Fregex.ref.regex%5Ftoken%5Fiterator.examples) is some example code that shows how to use regexes to split strings, using `boost::regex`.

Comment: Does not look like C++ to me. It's C++-CLI likly.

Comment: Oh right. VC++ is just the compiler. I mistook that for C++/CLI. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would be a better job for [System.CodeDom.Compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6b99ydt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) than for Regexes.

Answer (score 0):

If `boost` is an option for you, then you can use `boost::regex` with `boost::match_extra` flag, then `match_results::captures` and `sub_match::captures` contain list of all captured items